# 1/2” Vertical Hole in Floor Joist - What to do?

Tags: joists, crawlspace, hole-repair

First post here, hoping to get some help. I was recently trying to run a coax cable from my crawl space into my home office (there was an existing coax drop, but the cable seems to terminate somewhere in the attic and it’s difficult to access).

The problem I encountered was trying to drill down from behind the wall plate. I bought a 1/2” flex drill bit and started drilling down through the bottom plate, only to realize that the drill was still encountering resistance after a couple inches. I probably drilled down a few more inches, and then the torque was too much for my drill. Unfortunately, trying to reverse the drill made the drill bit snap…

From what I understand of the subfloor layout, and what I’ve seen underneath in the crawlspace, I most definitely drilled into the floor joist to some degree. I’m not sure if the hole was completely vertical, or slightly angled.

The joists are 2x10’s - and based on some rough math (total thickness of subfloor and length of flex bit), I estimate worst-case that the vertical hole extends about 4.5 inches into the joist (slightly less than 50% the nominal thickness of 9.25 inches).

At this point I’m not sure what to do. I don’t know if it’s possible to retrieve the snapped drill bit head. Should I leave it in there and just try to seal the hole? I am fairly certain that this isn’t a load bearing wall, but the joist is directly underneath a full wall that separates a bedroom from the kitchen.

Tl;dr - drilled down behind drywall, went a few inches into 2x10 floor joist, drill bit snapped off - next steps?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Diameter of bit is important, but around 1/2 inch would just get new bit and move over a few inches.  Don't use a pogo stick over it.

Comment: Just added - it was a 1/2” drill bit. 

What exactly is a pogo stick?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pogo_stick The point (pun intended) being that it puts tremendous pressure on a very small floor area. Which of course isn't going to happen inside your wall. **Don't worry about it.** and call the cost of a new drill bit to a "learning experience".

Comment: These youngsters don't know the fun of using a pogo on a joist.

Comment: Haha, I should have seen that coming…thanks everyone for putting my qualms to rest.